# Kubernetes/GCE Ingress controller fails

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-health-check

I'm new to Kubernetes and I'm trying to do HTTP Load Balancing on Google Container Engine with TLS (using the included GCE Ingress Controller). The error I have is repeatable even following [Google's official tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer). For readability I summarize the procedure in `config.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    name: nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    name: nginx

---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: nginx
    servicePort: 80
```

Then:

```
kubectl create -f config.yaml
export NODE_PORT=$(kubectl get -o jsonpath="{.spec.ports[0].nodePort}" services nginx)
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-130-211-0-0-22   --source-ranges 130.211.0.0/22   --allow tcp:$NODE_PORT
curl <ip_of_load_balancer>
```

(I removed the tags on the firewall rule so it will apply for all).

But I get a `502 Server Error`, which [according to the docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/controllers/gce#troubleshooting) means it's likely bootstrapping (but it always stays like this). I can see on the console that the backend is unhealthy.

In the docs, to avoid this one needs:

- a firewall rule (which is done above)
- Service must respond with 200 (but I tested the `nginx` image locally and the service via a general Load Balancer, works fine)

So what is the cause of this error and how can I further debug this?

Comment: Can you start with creating a yaml file for your configuration? Then it is more clear of what is all in there.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left the cluster overnight and it is now working. It either seems it takes quite some to bootstrap or something was fixed on the Google Cloud side.

Comment: It does take as much as a few minutes for an L7 load-balancer to come up.